# Adding data to a static force-directed graph has unexpected results

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 to create a static force directed graph. The graph itself renders fine initially, but when I add data to the graph, the link for the new node is longer than the existing links. Looking at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spencercarnage/mTX8u/1/) you can see the erratic behavior that happens when data is added after the first initial rendering.

The code I'm using to create the graph:

```
var width  = 500,
    height = 500;

var drawCount = 0;

var linkSelection,
    nodeSelection,
    nodes = [{
        id: 0,
    }, {    
        id: 1
    }, {
        id: 2
    }, {
        id: 3
    }],
    connections = [{
        from: 0,
        to: 1
    }, {
        from: 1,
        to: 2
    }, {
        from: 1,
        to: 3
    }],
    links = [];

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(50)
    .charge(-500)
    .friction(0.9)
    .size([width, height])
    .on('tick', tick);

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

nodeSelection = svg.selectAll('.node');
linkSelection = svg.selectAll('.link');

var dataMap = nodes.reduce(function(map, node) {
    map[node.id] = node;
    return map;
}, {});

connections.forEach(function (connection) {
    var parent = dataMap[connection.from];
    var child = dataMap[connection.to];

    if (child) {
        (parent.children || (parent.children = [])).push(child);
    } 
});

function setUpNodes() {
    // Align unbranched root node
    alignUnbranched(nodes[0]);
}

function setUpLinks() {
    // set up links
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
}

function updateLinks() {
    // update links
    linkSelection = linkSelection.data(links);
}

function cleanUpLinks() {
    // clean up any existing links that might be there
    linkSelection.exit().remove();
}

function appendLinks() {
    // Append links
    linkSelection.enter()
        .insert('line', '.node')
            .attr('class', 'link')
            .style('stroke', function (d) { return 'red'; })
            .style('stroke-width', '15px');
}

function startLayout() {
    // start the layout
    force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links);
}

function updateNodes() {
    // update nodes
    nodeSelection = nodeSelection.data(force.nodes());
}

// clean up nodes that might be there
function cleanUpNodes() {
    nodeSelection.exit().remove();
}

function appendNodes() {
    nodeSelection.enter()
        .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x; })
            .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y; })
            .attr('r', 15);
}

function draw() {
    console.log('here');
    setUpNodes();
    setUpLinks();

    if (drawCount === 0) {
      startLayout();
    }

    updateLinks();
    cleanUpLinks();
    appendLinks();
    updateNodes();
    cleanUpNodes();
    appendNodes();

    force.start();

    if (drawCount === 0) {
        // The following while statement helps us with producing a fixed layout
        // without the bouncy physics from a D3 forced directed layout.
        var n = 1000;
        var i = 0;

        while (i < n) {
            force.tick();
            i++;
        }

        force.stop();

        drawCount++;
    }
};

function tick() {
    linkSelection
        .attr('x1', function (d) { return d.source.x; }) 
        .attr('y1', function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x2', function (d) { 
            if (isNaN(d.target.x)) {
                console.log(d.target);
            }
            return d.target.x; 
        })
        .attr('y2', function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    nodeSelection.attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    });
}

function alignUnbranched(node, parent) {
    parent = parent || {x:0, y:0};

    node.fixed = true;
    node.y = parent.y + 50;
    node.x = width / 2;

    if (typeof node.children !== 'undefined' && node.children.length === 1) {
        alignUnbranched(node.children[0], node);
    }
}

var n = 3;

setTimeout(function () {
    n++;

    var node = {
        id: n++
    };

    nodes.push(node);
    nodes[1].children.push(node);
    draw();
}, 1500);

draw();
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is. The force layout lays out a graph, and this is what is has decided to do in this case. You can affect the layout by playing around with `.linkDistance()`, `.charge()`, etc.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I updated the text above to clarify the problem. What I want is for the ```linkDistance()``` and ```charge()``` to behave same for adding data as they do when the graph is initially rendered.

Comment: Well the result that you're seeing is simply how the layout behaves with your specific combination of static/non-static layout and fixed/non-fixed nodes. Compare with the [completely non-static version](http://jsfiddle.net/mTX8u/2/).

Comment: I am well aware of how the non-static version would work. What I'm looking for is a solution where I can apply some extra logic to my specific combination so that it behaves a little less erratic when adding additional data to it. If you have a potential solution, feel free to leave an answer!

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mTX8u/3/) with a larger link distance?